# Redirection by Vite like proxy or external 301 redirect

Tags: vite

how i can set redirect by pattern by Vite?

Example site up on

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

I request image like this

```
http://localhost:3000/2a84a6ddfd2c.png
```

or

```
http://localhost:3000/test/2a84a6ddfd2c.png
```

should redirect (internal like proxy OR if 301 redirect) by Vite to

```
http://imageHosting/2a84a6ddfd2c.png
http://imageHosting/test/2a84a6ddfd2c.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `vite.config.ts` (or `vite.config.js`), you can define the `server.proxy` properties to use regex.

So, for your specific example, you can:

- match both with `test` or without - `(\/test)?`
- match the hex string filename with `png` extension: `\/[a-fA-f0-9]+\.png`

So the section in your vite.config file will look like:

```
server {
  proxy: {
    "^(\/test)?\/[a-fA-f0-9]+\.png": {
      target: "http://imageHosting",
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
    },
    [... additional proxy rules]
  }
}
```